# Using the most recent version of zarith with opam

Tags: ocaml, opam

I am using `zarith` for handling arbitrary sized  integers.

The most recent version I could find on `opam.ocaml.org` was v1.9.1 (published in August 2019). On the project's github page I read `Latest commit a9a309d on 23 Jan` (2020).

I'd like to switch to the newer version, but how do I do that? I want to

1. keep `opam` happy, and
2. always use the most current version of zarith.

Please help!

Comment: Even though Github shows 16 new commits as compared to v1.9.1 on master, no new release has been made.  So you are technically at the latest released version.  I'm not an OCaml developer, but it appears that you cannot just tell opam to use master of the Git repo either.  I could be wrong here, but looking at the manual for opam, it appears it only works with repos of packages, which Zarith is not.  If there's something missing in v1.9.1 that you need, you might be able to ask the Zarith developer to cut a new release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use the unreleased, in-development version of zarith you can use the `--dev-repo` option of `opam pin add`:

```sh
opam pin add --dev-repo zarith
opam install zarith
```

Comment: My workaround was to download the current master of `zarith`, build it and use some hardcoded paths for `ocamlopt` when compiling my code... what you are proposing is clearly better: it even works for different `opam` switches. Thank you!

Comment: The latest zarith exposes more of GMP: fac, fac2, bin, ...

Comment: OTOH idk if this is mirrored (yet) by the zarith stubs for JS.

Comment: Note that the two shell commands mentioned in this accepted answer are incomplete-or-redundant…: either one needs to add the `-n` flag to the `opam pin add` command (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62503722/9164010)), or the `opam install zarith` command should just be skipped (it is implied by the `opam pin add` command itself).

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, currently 1.9.1 is both the latest version of Zarith available as an `opam` package (https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/zarith/) and as a GitHub tag (https://github.com/ocaml/Zarith/tags).

However, given this upstream Git repository also contains an [`.opam` specification file](https://github.com/ocaml/Zarith/blob/master/zarith.opam), you can just as well use `opam` to install the latest development version available in the `master` branch, or if need be, a precise Git commit just by relying on the so-called [pinning feature of `opam`](http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Usage.html#opam-pin).

So, you can run alternatively:

```
opam pin add -n -y -k git zarith.dev --dev-repo
```

or

```
opam pin add -n -y -k git zarith.dev "https://github.com/ocaml/Zarith.git#master"
```

or

```
opam pin add -n -y -k git zarith.dev "https://github.com/ocaml/Zarith.git#a9a309d0596d93b6c0c902951e1cae13d661bebd"
```

Then:

```
opam install zarith
```

#### Further details on the opam-pin command

1. The `.dev` version suffix is unneeded syntactically, but is recommended actually, as the [zarith.opam](https://github.com/ocaml/Zarith/blob/master/zarith.opam) file does not specify any version. To be more precise:

   - If you have other dependencies that would complain of `zarith.dev` when being installed, you can replace the version suffix of `dev` with any compatible version string, "close" to the commit or branch you selected.
   - However if you omit this version, `opam` will typically pick the latest version string from the [`opam` package repository](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/) (i.e., 1.9.1), which wouldn't necessarily match the code of the Git branch or commit you selected.
2. `-n`, `-y`, and `-k` are the short form of the options:

   - `--no-action` (don't install the package readily but wait the subsequent `opam install` command),
   - `--yes` (answer potential yes/no questions without prompting − a common `opam pin` question is `Package foo does not exist, create as a NEW package? [Y/n]` if ever you'd want to install a custom package not yet released in the [opam-repository](https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository)),
   - `--kind=KIND` (as there are several `KINDS` of pinning, the most typical being `version`, `path`, and `git`)